# Why did al-Qaeda attack the US during 9/11?

Tags: united-states, terrorism, middle-east, afghanistan, taliban

So I'm sitting here watching the news trying to figure out / remind myself why we were in Afghanistan. I figured we were there so that we could prevent further attacks from al-Qaeda.

That makes sense to me but now this makes me wonder why the al-Qaeda attacked us in the first place. Did we do something wrong to them? Do they not like democracy or believe in people voting for themselves on issues like we do over here? I thought originally we did a good job at helping the people over thereby equipping the government there with weapons so that they could defend themselves and by providing opportunities for women that the Taliban didn't believe in.

But now the president of Afghanistan seems to be shoving away his responsibilities by leaving the country and the Taliban runs the place. So now I'm assuming all those people have to live in fear of warlords now.

This leads me to my original question. Why did al-Qaeda attack the US in the first place? What did we even do to them?

Comment: There is a large and extensive wikipedia entry for 9/11.  Did you look at it?  I mean, I don't want to imply that wikipedia is THE authoritative source.  But it is a readily available one and any search on 9/11 events would return others as well.  The reason you are getting downvotes is probably because people feel this would be an easy answer to find by oneself.  Or at least, a minimal amount of research would have resulted in a different question.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I think there's [something to be said in favor of questions containing (commonly held) misconceptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33535). As the linked Meta answer says, someone else may be under the same misconception, stumble upon this post and learn something. :)

Comment: To the original poster, you are getting downvotes because the Taliban did not attack the US on 2001 September 11. That attack was performed, as the one answer says, by al-Qaeda rather the Taliban. You could get rid of many of those downvotes if you change your question to "Why did the Taliban provide safe harbor to al-Qaeda before and after the September 11 attack?"

Comment: @DavidHammen that seems more like a follow-up question though. While this question lacks research, that doesn't mean it's not useful to others (who also haven't done the research or find the question after a specific Google search). If you'd like to answer the other question, feel free to ask and answer it yourself (or wait for someone else to ask it).

Comment: @JJJ The intent is also to let people know *why* they are getting downvoted.  I didn't downvote, but when I made this comment, 3 people had done so, no reason given.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I **did** downvote, and when I do that I tend to provide a reason for my downvote, especially if the question is rescuable and no one has yet commented on their downvote.

Comment: I downvoted because the question is "we", "we", "we". Not everyone on here is American.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why did the Taliban attack the US in the first place? What did we even do to them?

The Taliban didn't attack the US. The September 11 attacks were committed by al-Qaeda. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility_for_the_September_11_attacks):

> At around 9:30 pm on September 11, 2001, George Tenet, director of the Central Intelligence Agency (CIA) told the president and U.S. senior officials inside the bunker underneath the White House that the CIA's Counterterrorism Center had determined that Osama Bin Laden and al-Qaeda were behind the September 11 attacks. Two weeks after 9/11, the Federal Bureau of Investigation connected the hijackers to al-Qaeda, a militant Salafist Islamist multi-national organization.

Afghanistan was invaded because the Taliban (who ruled in Afghanistan) provided harbor to al-Qaeda. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Qaeda#Refuge_in_Afghanistan):

> After the fall of the Afghan communist regime in 1992, Afghanistan was effectively ungoverned for four years and plagued by constant infighting between various mujahideen groups.[citation needed] This situation allowed the Taliban to organize.

> In 1996, Taliban-controlled Afghanistan provided a perfect staging ground for al-Qaeda. While not officially working together, Al-Qaeda enjoyed the Taliban's protection and supported the regime in such a strong symbiotic relationship that many Western observers dubbed the Taliban's Islamic Emirate of Afghanistan as, "the world's first terrorist-sponsored state."

According to NATO ([statement by then NATO Secretary General Lord Robertson on 2 October 2001](https://www.nato.int/docu/speech/2001/s011002a.htm)):

> Today's was classified briefing and so I cannot give you all the details. Briefings are also being given directly by the United States to the Allies in their capitals.
>
> The briefing addressed the events of 11 September themselves, the results of the investigation so far, what is known about Osama bin Laden and the Al-Qaida organisation and their involvement in the attacks and in previous terrorist activity, and the links between Al-Qaida and the Taleban regime in Afghanistan.
>
> The facts are clear and compelling. The information presented points conclusively to an Al-Qaida role in the 11 September attacks.
>
> We know that the individuals who carried out these attacks were part of the world-wide terrorist network of Al-Qaida, headed by Osama bin Laden and his key lieutenants and protected by the Taleban.
>
> On the basis of this briefing, it has now been determined that the attack against the United States on 11 September was directed from abroad and shall therefore be regarded as an action covered by Article 5 of the Washington Treaty, which states that an armed attack on one or more of the Allies in Europe or North America shall be considered an attack against them all.

---

Why did al-Qaeda attack the US? Again, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks#Motives):

> Osama bin Laden's declaration of a holy war against the United States, and a 1998 fatwā signed by bin Laden and others, calling for the killing of Americans, are seen by investigators as evidence of his motivation. In bin Laden's November 2002 "Letter to America", he explicitly stated that al-Qaeda's motives for their attacks include:
> U.S. support of Israel
>
> - support for the "attacks against Muslims" in Somalia
> - support of Philippines against Muslims in the Moro conflict
> - support for Israeli "aggression" against Muslims in Lebanon
> - support of Russian "atrocities against Muslims" in Chechnya
> - pro-American governments in the Middle East (who "act as your agents") being against Muslim interests
> - support of Indian "oppression against Muslims" in Kashmir
> - the presence of U.S. troops in Saudi Arabia
> - the sanctions against Iraq

As you can see, none of the motives for al-Qaeda's attack on the US relate to Afghanistan.

Of course the above may sound a lot like political campaign points. Another explanation for the terrorist acts is, as quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motives_for_the_September_11_attacks):

> The U.S. government took the position, as often repeated by the Bush Administration, that terrorists attacked the United States because "they hate us for our freedoms." For example, President George W. Bush in a speech to Congress nine days after the attacks said: "They hate right what we see in this chamber--a democratically elected government. Their leaders are self-appointed. They hate our freedoms--our freedom of religion, our freedom of speech, our freedom to vote and assemble and disagree with each other."

Comment: Nice summary (and upvoted by me) except for the last part. They hate being told that **they** cannot have a theocracy where they live. Not having a theocracy worldwide is secondary to that.

Comment: @o.m. yea, just wanted to include two points of view regarding motives. Just citing a terror group or just citing President Bush might make it seem like I'm picking sides when both of them could be seen as biased.

Comment: In addition, post 9/11 the Afghani Taliban offered to hand over Bin Laden (to a third party Islamic country for trial, supposedly) if the US provided proof he was responsible for the WTC attack. The offer was rejected. Link from guardian: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2001/oct/14/afghanistan.terrorism5

Comment: @JJJ, Where possible citations and quotes should support an actual answer; the two quotes at the end undermine that purpose.  If you consider both quotes biased, this implies you're contemplating some straighter (*i.e.* less biased) answer.  Please clarify.

Comment: @agc Think of it as 'one man's terrorist being another man's freedom fighter'. The two conflicting citations indicate that both are popular views, one from the perspective of enemies of al-Qaeda and one from the perspective of the groups (main) enemy. I'm not sure what you mean by a 'straighter answer', I don't think there's some middle ground and I think both positions are relevant to understand the different perspectives. The internal view is relevant to understanding motivations for nine eleven while the external view is relevant for understand the US response.

Comment: @JJJ, Re *"The two conflicting citations"*, *"I don't think there's some middle ground"*:  but those two quotes aren't mutually exclusive -- like many, or perhaps all, empires, the US could at once be internationally oppressive, and also be domestically rather too well pleased with its conduct.

Answer (score -3):

The existing answer is correct, but I'll add mine because there is another flaw hidden in your question and an important point was not covered.

You assume that the events of 9/11 were the reason for the wars that followed. But actually only a small fraction of all the military power deployed in the invasions of Iraq and Afghanistan was used to chase those related to the 9/11 attacks.

This is more evident for the Iraq war. From the beginning it was known that most of the 9/11 attackers came from Saudi Arabia and it was evident that people from that country organised the attack. No investigation made any connection with Iraq or the Iraqi regime, not even Bush or his administration tried to make any connection. Instead they created the [WMD Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction) ans used it to justify the US Invasion.

For Afghanistan this is less evident, but not so different. The Taliban were an organisation [created in Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taliban#History) by people educated and trained in Pakistan that conquered the country by force. Therefore the Afghan people were not responsible for their actions. None the less most of the military effort was dedicated to the occupation of the country, while so little was dedicated to hunt [Osama bin Laden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osama_bin_Laden) and the [Mullah Omar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammed_Omar), who was accused of sheltering him, that they could easily escape and remain in hiding for the following years.

**Update:**
I see that you changed the subject from the Taliban to al Qaeda, but you still keep the focus on Afghanistan. That is not correct. The old part of the answer written above is still valid, but there is something else to add.

Apart from being the country where Osama bin Laden was, when the attack happened, Afghanistan had no role in the motivations behind the 9/11 attack. As I wrote before it was perpetrated by Saudi citizens and if you want to know why it happened you have to look at what was the situation back then in Saudi Arabia. 
So when you write:

> I figured we were there so that we could prevent further attacks from al-Qaeda.

Until you try to figure based on the view you have of Afghanistan you cannot reach any conclusion that makes any sense. Especially when you write:

> Do they not like democracy or believe in people voting for themselves?

You don't take into account that Saudi Arabia was not and is not a democracy.